# generating and using all IP addresses with php

Tags: php, list, for-loop, ip

knowing nothing about java (I thought a thread on this same topic for java) and a tiny bit about php, I was wondering how I could generate, **with php**, a complete list of all the possible IPs (0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) and then how I can use each of those in a php script that is intended to test a IP verification tool that I am trying to set up (take each one of them and use it).

For the second part of the question, I was thinking about using a foreach statement or using the part of the "testing code" inside the loop that would generate each IP combination, so that it is tested as the IPs are generated.

Then for the first part, I have to admit that I am stuck and that my basic knowledge doesn't enable me to find a satisfying solution
So far I have come with this:

```
function gen() {
    $n1 = 0;
    $n2 = 0;
    $n3 = 0;
    $n4 = 0;

    while ($n4 <= 255 && $n3 <= 255) {
        echo $n1.'.'.$n2.'.'.$n3.'.'.$n4++.'<br>';
        echo $n1.'.'.$n2.'.'.$n3++.'.'.$n4.'<br>';
    }
}
gen();
```

which just partially does what I want.

Comment: At face value this seems insane - how are you going to 'verify' addresses against the generated ones?

Comment: Well... All IPv4 might be generated by using 4 simple loops, one in another, something like `for ($n1 = 0; $n1 <= 255; ++$n1) { for ($n2 = 0; $n2 <= 255; ++$n2) { /* same for $n3 and $n4 */ { { $ip = "$n1.$n2.$n3.$n4". } } } }`, but that's just silly! Even if storing IP as 32bit integer (which is smallest value that can be used for storing individual IP address), you would need 16 gigabytes of memory. It would also take enormous amount of time to generate it. And don't forget about IPv6 addresses...

Comment: Pick one of the two, generation or validation, not both.  Generating all "valid" (just because all the quads are between 0 and 255 doesn't mean they're technically valid) IP addresses is not a good way to validate incoming addresses.  Also, decide what the addresses are being used for and that will get rid of chunks of IPs (127.* and 192.* are not valid internet IPs).

Comment: I need to generate the list as to check the addresses in the list

Comment: $randIP = rand(100,254).'.'.rand(100,254).'.'.rand(100,254).'.'.rand(100,254);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than generating a possible database / storage for ~4 billion IP4 addresses (assuming you are only looking at IPv4 ignoring all IPv6 addresses) would it not be easier, and more practical just generate random IP address combinations to test with, which you can easily validate with RegEx?

The following regex would allow you to validate any particular IPv4 address from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`

What you do need to remember however is that not all combinations of addresses are classed as 'valid' even if they are syntax correct.

Another alternative (as also mentioned by @binaryLV) is using the PHP filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP); function which is nice and clean. Check the flags out to help filter too over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

**Update**

For IP location based services I would recommend using a service such as [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/index.php). They provide both an [API (see here)](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) to use which allows you to call their service reducing the need to store the information on your database. Else they offer a [database of IP addresses (see here)](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php) to xxx.xxx.xxx precision that can also be downloaded.

Comment: @lethalMango, do I know you as MangoMotion from another forum?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian, as much as I have practised and tried at being two people at once I never quite managed it.. so I stuck with lethalMango and it must be someone else :)

Comment: I would use `filter_val()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP` to validate IP address... It's much cleaner than silly regexp.

Comment: @binaryLV - I had just added that in, added your name too.. if you want to add it as a separate answer let me know and I'll take it out :)

Comment: @lethalMango, if I knew what author needs, I might post an answer... Though, I can't really understand what author wants to achieve. He also states that he tries to set up some IP verification tool (*3rd party?*), so I'm not sure if he's interested in different ways of filtering valid IP addresses.

Comment: thank you very much to you all!
What I want to achieve in a first time is to check the location of IPs, displayed on a webpage (I have a list of users with their IPs and I want to check their country of origin).
So I won't be needing to store all the IP combinations in a database as the first 16 bits enable to identify the country of origin (I don't need the city or the region or something else).
So I am trying to get all the results for the various combinations of the 16 first digits and then to group them (as specific ranges of IPs come from the same country)

Comment: @lethalMango - thank you very much for the link! I just had a look on their website and it looks like that it is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Iam Zesh - no worries at all :) If that answers your question could you be so kind as to mark it so with the tick to the left of my answer :) If there is anything else just comment back

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops:

```
for($n1=0; $n1 < 256; $n1++) {
    for($n2=0; $n2 < 256; $n2++) {
        for($n3=0; $n3 < 256; $n3++) {
            for($n4=0; $n4 < 256; $n4++) {
                echo $n1 . "." . $n2 . "." . $n3 . "." . $n4 . "\n";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need few 4GB RAM plates, few multi-core CPUs and loads of time to handle this... On both ends (server and client).

Comment: I fail to see where lots of RAM is needed here, we only have 4 integers of memory used. Oh and yes, it does take a while.

Comment: @igorw, we don't have 4 integers there. We have 256^4 IP addresses that have to be stored somewhere somehow. If we store each of them as 32bit integer, it takes 16GB (256*256*256*256*4 bytes). If we store them as strings, it takes even more.

Comment: And what indicates that these addresses will be stored in RAM?

Comment: @igorw, and what indicates that they wont be stored in RAM? Who knows, maybe author has modified PHP source and `echo` throws data to `/dev/null` instead of outputting it... Or even better - maybe he has some alien technologies that are able to do in 1 second more work than thousands of billions of human high-tech technologies. Anyway, doing such loops is something much worse than just a "terrible idea".

Comment: @igorw, @Ed Manet: no alien technologies, and also not so much RAM...
what about only usin the 2 first 16bit integers?

Comment: If you guys think this is bad, wait until someone updates the question for IPv6...